# Change selected elements of character vector

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a shorter version for the folowing principle to rename certain columns of a data frame?

```
data1<-data.frame("a"=1:3,"b"=1:3,"c"=1:3)

data1Names<-names(data1)
data1Names[data1Names=="a"]<-"hello"
data1Names[data1Names=="c"]<-"world"
names(data1)<-data1Names
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `match` to replace selected elements and to respect the order when using `names<-`...

```
names(data1)[ match( c("a", "c") , names(data1) ) ] <- c("hello", "world")
#  hello b world
#1     1 1     1
#2     2 2     2
#3     3 3     3
```

Swapping the desired order of renaming...

```
names(data1)[ match( c("c", "a") , names(data1) ) ] <- c("hello", "world")
#  world b hello
#1     1 1     1
#2     2 2     2
#3     3 3     3
```

Answer (score 5):

The `data.table` package has a `setnames` function that will work on `data.frames`

```
library(data.table)
data1<-data.frame("a"=1:3,"b"=1:3,"c"=1:3)
#setnames(data1, "a", "hello")
#setnames(data1, "c", "world")
# or in one step
setnames(data1, c("a", "c"), c("hello", "world"))
data1
#  hello b world
#1     1 1     1
#2     2 2     2
#3     3 3     3
```

All of the answers so far will make a copy of the `data.frame`.  `setnames` has the added benefit that it changes the names by reference, *without making a copy of the data.frame*.

Answer (score 4):

`setNames` can be helpful

```
> setNames(data1, c("hello", "b", "world"))
  hello b world
1     1 1     1
2     2 2     2
3     3 3     3
```

another alternative

```
> names(data1)[names(data1) %in% c("a", "c")] <- c("hello", "world")
> data1
  hello b world
1     1 1     1
2     2 2     2
3     3 3     3
```

Comment: Thx again, but therefore I have to know the order of the columns in the data.frame

Comment: But why not just use `names(data1)<- c("hello","b","world")` or `names(data1)[c(1,3)]<-c("hello","world")`

Comment: Because I do not know about the order of the columns in the data.frame.

Comment: So @klaus , again I say to you please take more time and describe your initial problem more carefully. You don't mention this in the OP at all.

Comment: The second alternative is useful if you dont have/know the order of the columns. Btw pay attention to @SimonO101's 2nd comment.

Comment: With `setnames` in the `data.table` package you don't need to know the order.

Comment: `names(data1)[names(data1) %in% c("a", "c")] <- c("hello", "world")`  this is what I used before but it will not work in every case. because there for I have to know that column with name "a" comes before "c" otherwise "a" becomes "world".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rename` from the **plyr** package:

```
data1<-data.frame("a"=1:3,"b"=1:3,"c"=1:3)
> rename(data1,c('a' = 'hello','b' = 'world'))
  hello world c
1     1     1 1
2     2     2 2
3     3     3 3
```